# Mysql assigning default causes error

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run the below query to create a table in mysql and I am getting an error.

```
create table newtable ( 
       version_id int(11) auto_increment not null, 
       test_id int(11)   default version_id, 
       primary key(version_id) 
 );

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'version_id not null, primary key(version_id), unique key(test_id) )' at line 1
```

I am getting above error.

I think the problem is setting test_id default as version_id, because it works otherwise.

Thank you
Bala

```
-- Update
```

Here is what I wanted to do,

When i create a new row, I want to use the version_id as the key. When I update, I want to use the value of existing record as the key. Note that test_id is not the primary key.

Comment: your update isn't clear... does that information change my answer at all? You can also add triggers to before or after update if you so desire...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use "variables" as defaults. They probably have to be constants. If you want to get this effect, you could probably do it in a stored procedure / trigger "before Insert" such that if the trial_id is not supplied it gets assigned the same value as the version_id...

Here's [a tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0260__Trigger/Beforeinserttrigger.htm) that might help you toward that end.

I think your trigger would look something like:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
    -> BEFORE INSERT ON newtable
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->      IF NEW.trial_id IS NULL THEN
    ->         SET NEW.trial_id = NEW.version_id;
    ->      END IF;
    -> END$$
```